# How to see if mapView is touched or not?

Tags: android, android-mapview

It is a situation when:
`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is done.

But user don't take away his finger(no `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)`

mapView.isPressed() - no:(

Comment: isPressed() is inherited from the View class, which basically indicates if a button is currently in its "down" state. What you could do is make a flag of your own that's turned on with "ACTION_DOWN" and turned off with "ACTION_UP".

Answer (score 2):

create a new class:

```
public class CustomOverlay extends Overlay
{
     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapview)
     {

         if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         {
             //put your code;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

in MapActivity put this code in onCreate method:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.MapView);
CustomOverlay customOverlay = new CustomOverlay();
List<Overlay> listOverlay = mapView.getOverlays();        
listOverlay.add(customOverlay);
```

I hope this help you.